# What is the best option to have the same data in identical tables in different databases?

Tags: mariadb, replication

I have three MariaDB databases with same tables structure on the same server.
Some data should be identical in all databases.

Is wildcard replication the best option?

Comment: Had a view in TRIGGERS and VIEWS. I would prefer a solution in my.cnf or an extra add-on rather on the source code.

Comment: Best option for doing what???

Comment: For having identical tables in different database on the same server. Best without changing the source code only adjusting the server config.

Comment: I'm still lost.  Is this about Replication?  If so, why are you not simply replicating everything?  If it is about triggers/views, then what is their issue?  Sure, you need to create new triggers/views when a new db is added; but that is not "replication", it is simply something you do along with `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I see. Of course it is about the data in the tables. I adjusted my question. As far as i have read replication is only possible between tables of two databases.
In my case I have data entered in a table in three databases and it should be added/updated in all three.

Comment: Replication is between two _servers_.  "Database" is an ambiguous term.

Answer (score 0):

If the data stays identical among the databases, don't copy the table.  Instead, have a 4th, say, `CREATE DATABASE common` that contains any "common" tables.

Then users would reference it via

```
    SELECT ... FROM common.table_name ...
```

Replication is between *servers*, not between *databases* on a single instance of mysql.